# Is an Identity Disc a long term requirement in the Grid?

Tags: tron-legacy, tron

In Tron and Tron: Legacy all people (programs, users, ISOs) are fitted with an Identity Disc. This disc apparently records everything that a person does, and if that disc is lost or damaged the person is threatened with immediate deresolution.

> ["You will receive an Identity Disc. Everything you do or learn will be imprinted on this disc. If you lose your disc or fail to follow commands, you will be subject to immediate deresolution."](http://tron.wikia.com/wiki/Identity_Disc)

But how necessary is it that someone in the system have an Identity Disc? Would someone in the system without a disc for an extended time start to degrade, forgetting things slowly until they derezzed "naturally"? Or would a person be able to live perfectly fine with out a disc, and the discs were merely tools used by oppressive regimes to track and record the lives of the people?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Identity Discs predate Clu taking over the Grid. However, in the film it's mostly an indicator of Clu's oppressive reign.  When the ISOs walked into the Grid, they didn't have Identity Discs.  Sam was able to exist just fine in the Grid without one.  However, because he didn't have one, he was instantly assumed to be criminal by the authorities on the Recognizer.  This is an equivalent to needing to keep your papers on you, so you can produce them when the cops say 'show me your papers!'

In addition, by having everyone carry recording devices on their person, any anti-Clu activities would be recorded on the disc.  This serves to provide Clu with a handy way to find programs who oppose him, and have them deleted.

It also served as an introduction to the idea of an identity disc and what features it has.  This later on was a key part of Clu's plan, as he was seeking Flynn's disc.

There's no indication that they're a requirement of existing in the Grid, they're simply tools.

Comment: In the TRON: Betrayal commic book, which precede CLU's Coup d'état, All programs, even ISO, wear a Identity disk.

Comment: It wasn't necessarily a function of CLU's regime, though he almost certainly made use of it. They existed in the original TRON movie as well. Also, in that movie, we see that the discs seem to be the means by which programs can exchange data with our world, ... when TRON sends his disc up into the communication stream, and Alan sends it back with instructions on it for how to destroy the MCP.

Comment: @DavRob60 Did that comic show if ISOs had identity discs when they were formed?

Comment: @keen No, the only ISO formation we see is [Ophelia](http://tron.wikia.com/wiki/Ophelia) the first ISO, And we only see her from front. (You could see some image of her formation on the link.)

Comment: @DavRob60 Darn, from my memory of the film, we only see the ISOs from the front when they originally walked to the Grid.

Comment: So to be clear, you do not feel that the ID was a necessity of being in the system, or on the Grid, and that someone in the system without an ID would be perfectly fine regardless of the duration (fine as far as not having a disc)?

Comment: @Xantec Yup.  We've never seen anyone lose their disc and start... degrading or dying.

Comment: Just rewatched the film, and the ISOs didn't have them when they were generated.

Answer (score 5):

There's the [*Identity*](http://tron.wikia.com/wiki/TRON%3a_Uprising_S1E5_Identity) episode of *TRON: Uprising* where Beck's identity disk is stolen.

He then start to get memory *glitch*.

He is  said that he will lost his memory forever and becomes a [stray](http://tron.wikia.com/wiki/Stray) if he don't recover it.

> Strays were rogue programs who lacked identity discs. During the rule of Clu, they would be rounded up by Guards and Sentries to be rectified. Sam Flynn was captured by Sentries when he entered the Tron System after it was found that he lacked a disc.
>
> Strays often lost their memory in fits called glitches after being parted from their disc for too long. A notable example of a stray is Beck, a program who's disc was stolen. After recovering his disc, his memories returned.

Answer (score 2):

You could look upon it as conceptually similar to a driver's license or maybe a key (although much more important). While you can function without one, having one allows you to do things that you cannot otherwise do.

The rods that are used to 'create' the lightcycles are a similar metaphor, they are items that enable an activity.

However without a disc I imagine most programs would be very vulnerable to damage as they would have no backup to recover from. When Flynn repairs Cora after her injury he would probably not have been able to do so without her disc to hand.